# creating a global counter/ Auto increment in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service `helper` as follows:

```
var globalUniqueId = 0;

var getNextId = function(){
    globalUniqueId += 1;
    return globalUniqueId;
}

return {
    getNextId: getNextId
}
```

Then I inject this service in other controllers and each gets a unique id and uses another service to push data into an shared Array

```
anotherService.AddRecord(helper.getNextId(),mydata);
```

anotherService:

```
AddRecord(id,mydata){
    mydata.id = id;
    myarray.push(mydata);
}
```

But I am getting dup error which shouldnt happen because I am generating a unique id in the array and do when i display using `ng-repeat` i should not need `track by $index`. Is there something wrong in this code?

Comment: More efficient to use `track by $index` anyway. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Answer (score 0):

If you use code like:

```
anotherService.AddRecord(helper.getNextId(),mydata);
anotherService.AddRecord(helper.getNextId(),mydata);
```

this will add same object twice.

Comment: Hi @Petr Thats what is happening, shouldnt it be different? because I am adding that id to the object before pushing into my array.?